# Getting trouble in saving data to a mysql using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the very basic technique of AJAX to save the form into a database using AJAX.

However I am having some trouble.

All I searched, I was getting jQuery code, but I want to do this with simple AJAX only.

HTML FORM:

```
<form id="submitcourse" name="submitcourse" method="get">
<p>Course Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cvalue" id="cvalue" /></p>
<a href="#" onclick="submitformwithajax();">Successfull</a>

</form>
<span id="result">.</span>
```

AJAX CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        if(window.ActiveXobject)
        {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return null;

    }
    function submitformwithajax()
    {
        var myAjaxPostrequest=new GetXmlHttpObject();

        var coursename=document.submitcourse.cvalue.value;

        var parameter="cvalue="+coursename;

        myAjaxPostrequest.open("GET", "do.php", true)
        myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myAjaxPostrequest.send(parameter)
        myAjaxPostrequest.onreadystatechange=function{
            if(myAjaxPostrequest.readyState==4){
                if(myAjaxPostrequest.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=myAjaxPostrequest.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("submitcourse").style.display="none";
                }
                else
                document.getElementById("submitcourse").innerHTML="An error has occured making the request";

            }
        }
    }




    </script>
```

The purpose of the above AJAX code is to send the form details to do.php File, where I can work on the data received.

do.php File :

```
<?php
$course=$_REQUEST['cvalue'];
echo "dddd".$course;


?>
```

Right now I am not able to get the value in the do.php file, Please help me out,

NOTE: I have the code to do this using jQuery, but I want to do it in this method only. Since it is for teaching students about Basic AJAX.

Comment: so what output is coming?

Comment: Try using some addon like firebug to see what data is being sent to your php file. Also try this var_dump($_GET) in your php file.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, There is no output.

Comment: There is a missing semicolon on this line myAjaxPostrequest.open("GET", "do.php", true)

Comment: @Suyash 
Tried Var_dump and fixed semicolon still no response

Comment: @TangoTango did you check in firebug for what values are being passed to the php file?

Answer (score 6):

Right off the bat I'm noticing that you don't have () after your function definition...

```
myAjaxPostrequest.onreadystatechange=function{
```

Should be

```
myAjaxPostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, I thought it looked funny.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: you put your parameter inside send(), which is not correct, because you sending GET request, change your code to:

```
myAjaxPostrequest.open("GET", "do.php?"+parameter, true)
myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myAjaxPostrequest.send()
```

Using Ajax GET, the parameter should be mixed with the URL, however, your code is correct for POST method.

or if you want to use POST

```
myAjaxPostrequest.open("POST", "do.php", true)
myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myAjaxPostrequest.send(parameter)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i don't know how i missed it.. Thanks, It worked .. :)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can't get away with using getElementsByName instead

```
var coursename=document.getElementsByName('cvalue')[0].value;
```

Comment: Tried, i think it improved something, because initially it was not giving any response but now it is at least showing error http://prntscr.com/x2hu2

Comment: and also, I advise against using, much less teaching, $_REQUEST.  If you plan to look at a POST value, then you should use the $_POST superglobal.. the same for $_GET, they should not be combined.

Comment: But the problem is, y it is unset